# How to create ink splash that extends beyond GridView image?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a grid of images with a 'Share' button in the top-right corner of each image.  The problem is the ink splash from the IconButton doesn't extend beyond the image border.  Also, it seems that there is both an ink splash on the IconButton AND an ink splash in the InkWell - there should only be one splash on the button.

I know that the ink splash is rendered on the Material layer, but I cannot seem to get that layer beyond the bounds of the image.  Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

_buildGrid() {
  List<String> imgs = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Three_Sisters_Sunset.jpg/1280px-Three_Sisters_Sunset.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Opera_House_and_ferry._Sydney.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/State_Library_of_New_South_Wales_Reading_Room_2017.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Sydney_Harbour_Bridge_from_Circular_Quay.jpg/2880px-Sydney_Harbour_Bridge_from_Circular_Quay.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Amptower_centerpoint.jpg/800px-Amptower_centerpoint.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Summer_at_Manly_Beach.jpg/2560px-Summer_at_Manly_Beach.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Glasshouse.JPG/2560px-Glasshouse.JPG"
  ];
  return new GridView.extent(
    primary: true,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
    childAspectRatio: 210.0 / 130.0,
    children: imgs.map((id) => _buildThumbnail(id)).toList(),
  );
}

_buildThumbnail(String url) {
  return new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      border: new Border.all(
        color: Colors.black45,
        width: 1.0,
      ),
    ),
    child: new Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Center(
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.image,
            color: Colors.black45,
          ),
        ),
        new Image.network(
          url,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          key: new Key("thumnail-$url"),
          gaplessPlayback: false,
        ),
        new Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () => print("Open image: $url"),
            child: new Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.topRight,
              child: new IconButton(
                  splashColor: Colors.red,
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.share),
                  onPressed: () => print("Share image: $url"),
                  color: Colors.black87),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Grid Splash',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Grid Splash'),
        ),
        body: _buildGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an **InkResponse** widget to encapsulate the button widget.

Edit: Don't forget the enableFeedback attribute.

`new InkResponse(splashColor: someColor,
 enableFeedback: true,
 child: new IconButton(...)
)`

Comment: This won't change anything to the problem.

Comment: "An area of a Material that responds to touch. Has a configurable shape and can be configured to **clip splashes that extend outside its bounds** or not."

Comment: This was from the InkResponse documentation. also did the trick for me in my code.

Comment: @sofakingforever I tried using an InkResposne but it didn't work.  Specifically, I tried replacing "new IconButton(...)" with "new InkResponse(child: new IconButton(...)".  I also tried replacing IconButton with Icon, then putting the tap callback in the InkResponse - it still didn't work.

Comment: @Mark now that I'm looking at the code, maybe you didn't try the enableFeedback attribute. `new InkResponse( splashColor: someColor, enableFeedback: true, child: new IconButton(...))` That's the one that worked for me.